# How to binding TextBlock text in TabControl ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, tabcontrol

In sidebar menu(RTL) when i clicked on which one, a `TabItem` added to **tbMain**. My problem is that how i can show sidebar clicked text in `TabItem` header in `TextBlock` using `Binding`?

here is Image , XAML and CodeBehind.

[image]

XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tbMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="0">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#000000"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind :

```
public WinFinance() {
   
      InitializeComponent();

      var definitionsMenu = new List<MenuSubItems>();
      definitionsMenu.Add(new MenuSubItems("area", new ucrArea()));
      definitionsMenu.Add(new MenuSubItems("client", new ucrClient()));
      definitionsMenu.Add(new MenuSubItems("cash" , new ucrCash()));
      
      tbMain.Items.Add(new ucrMainControl());
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I will assume that you somehow made that `List<MenuSubItems>` as `ItemsSource` of `tbMain` in the part of code that you didn't uploaded.

In this case, If you want to make some `string` property("area", "client", "cash"...) as a `Header` of `TabItems`, You can use `Style` like:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tbMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="0">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding MenuSubHeader}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    .......
```

Then it will works.

Edit: This was my code-behind and `MenuSubItems` class I wrote. I don't have any knowledge about your project so I just wrote just to show how it works.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var definitionsMenu = new List<MenuSubItems>();
    definitionsMenu.Add(new MenuSubItems("area", new object()));
    definitionsMenu.Add(new MenuSubItems("client", new object()));
    definitionsMenu.Add(new MenuSubItems("cash", new object()));

    tbMain.ItemsSource = definitionsMenu;
}
```

```
public class MenuSubItems
{
    public string MenuSubHeader { get; set; }
    public object Content { get; set; }

    public MenuSubItems(string key, object value)
    {
        MenuSubHeader = key;
        Content = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer with my version of code behind. Please make sure that I don't know how your original code was looks like

Answer (score -1):

For it to be achieved the way you're XAML is wrote, you must have Items that has a property named Text (also, if you want it to update itself dynamically, implement INotifyProperty).
The best way to do that is by creating a ViewModel with the data you need and bind you're sidebar values with the same property that you bind the tabs.